# datatables for jquery 2.1.1 to make table header as dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a simple table like

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr> 
 </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I actually wanted the thead columns to behave like buttons for sorting table ascending or descending order-wise.
I found an option of using datatables plug-in which works like [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

But I am using jquery 2.1.1 and the above plug-in isn't available for this version.
I am bit confused of how to proceed further to make such implementation with my code.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"Stupid jQuery Table Sort" seems to fully support jquery 2+.

JSbin demo: http://jsbin.com/wimefeseni/1/edit?html,output

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("table").stupidtable();
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-sort="int">int</th>
    <th data-sort="float">float</th>
    <th data-sort="string">string</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>-.18</td>
    <td>banana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="awesome">
    <td>95</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>coke</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Link to plugin: http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/